# Are there any DNA base sequences that are fully conserved between the genomes of all humans?

Tags: genetics, dna, human-genome

That is, they don't differ throughout the entire population. I understand of course that we can't DNA sequence every human, so by "fully" I mean there's an incredibly small probability of there being a mutation retained in a living individual.

Also by the genome I'm referring to the consensus of all the cells composing in the individual.

I guess my question is really, where are the crucially important sections of DNA that are simply unmodifiable without being incompatible with life?

Answer (score 11):

In 2004 [Bejerano *et al.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15131266) identified "481 segments longer than 200 base pairs (bp) that are absolutely conserved (100% identity with no insertions or deletions) between orthologous regions of the human, rat, and mouse genomes". These were found to be mostly in/around genes related to RNA processing, which is perhaps unsurprising given that it is such a primitive/inherent biological process.

Bejerano's paper has been cited [over 500 times on Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/results/citedbyresults.url?sort=plf-f&cite=2-s2.0-2542542256&src=s&imp=t&sid=rnObiJAHVmr8LbB21Qi2qbD%3a200&sot=cite&sdt=a&sl=0&origin=recordpage&txGid=rnObiJAHVmr8LbB21Qi2qbD%3a20), with numerous papers reporting variants in such regions that cause diseases such as colorectal adenocarcinomas.

---

So few conserved regions exist because there is plenty of redundancy in the genome; many genes functionally overlap with others, and many genetic variants are 'silent' - they have no effect on the phenotype. Having this variability is advantageous in Darwinian terms because this increases the *evolvability* of the species.

There are many regions of very high homology between individuals (protein-coding regions are highly conserved even between species), but there will still be natural variation; each mutations effect will be dependent on the *rest* of the genome. Genes work together to produce a working organism - they do not each code for a little 'bit', and therefore a change in one portion of the DNA may be 'balanced' by a change elsewhere.

It is only in 'ultra-conserved' sequences that mutations are presumably incompatible with life because the process is so finely-tuned and indispensable.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the research link and explanation!

Comment: ahem, "very high homology"?

Comment: @bobthejoe, thanks for that constructive comment. Is the the 'very' you dislike? Or the 'high'? Or the combination of the 2 used with 'homology'? Degrees of homology are commonly used to describe the relatedness of 2 biological systems/molecules/processes... whatever.

Comment: @LukeTheDuke. Meaning that it is commonly used doesn't mean that it is appropriate. There shouldn't be degrees of homology, just homology. Yes, I am nitpicking but it is a concept that should be better enforced.