# Is there non-coding DNA common to all living things?

Tags: evolution, introns

I saw the question asked about proteins common to all life, and was happy to see there are proteins common to all living things. Similarly, I wonder if there are portions of non-coding DNA that are common to all living things too.

PS  This was NOT a homework question as the feedback indicated.  I was curious to know and didn't know where to turn so I asked Stack Exchange.  I am not a student, just a person who wants to understand life better.

Comment: Relevant link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_non-coding_sequence

Comment: There is an answered question about such conservation in eukaryotes here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/ . An intelligent reading of the answer suggests why this is unlikely to extend to prokaryotes.

Comment: @Jon unfortunately on SE.biology there is a confusing close vote reason which uses the term "homework" to really mean 'under researched'. I know that is confusing and irritating when your post gets closed using that reason when it is not a homework question. My advice would be to google around for an answer, show what you found and what you didn't understand, and then hopefully the question can be reopened. perhaps start with the wikipedia link I shared in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I did google around but just missed the answer I guess.  Anyway, no need to reopen since your comment pointed me to the answer.  Thank you!